# How to use the MongoDB group function via the new PHP pecl/mongodb driver (1.1.2) and library

Tags: php, mongodb

New driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver

New library: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

I have successfully selected the collection, listed the fields, set an order and used limit / skip.

Examples of this syntax can be found in the library's tests:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/tests/Collection/CrudSpec/FindFunctionalTest.php

However, I am struggling to find any documentation or syntax examples of how to use Mongos grouping functions via the PHP Library.

I can find plenty of examples of how to do this directly in MongoDB and via previous driver & library "aggregation" classes, but not via this new library.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the new `$collection->find()` function $options array does not accept a group parameter (unlike [sort, limit and batch size as per tests](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/tests/Collection/CrudSpec/FindFunctionalTest.php#L49)).

There don't seem to be any tests for grouping in the PHP Library, but I am now using the [MongoDB\Collection::aggregate() method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/api/class-MongoDB.Collection.html#_aggregate), which uses similar syntax to the legacy driver.

Example syntax:

```
<?php
$group_pipeline = [
    '$group' => [
        '_id' => [ 'event_type' => '$_id.eT' ],
        'total' => ['$sum' => 1 ],
    ],
];
$aggregation = $collection->aggregate([
    $match_pipeline,
    $group_pipeline,
    $sort_pipeline,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The group method in the old driver is merely a shortcut for the "group" command. The new driver (and library) don't have a method for it, but you can still *run* the group command yourself. We are tracking the addition of this helper in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-177.

The aggregation `$group` is similar, and is probably recommended as it does not go through JavaScript. Our documentation says on this:

> Because db.collection.group() uses JavaScript, it is subject to a number of performance limitations. For most cases the $group operator in the aggregation pipeline provides a suitable alternative with fewer restrictions.

The original group command can still be run with:

```
$ns = "databasename.collectionname";
$cmd = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command( [
    'group' => [
        'ns' => $ns,
        'key' => $key, // (or '$keyf' if you're passing in a MongoCode object)
        '$reduce' => $reduce,
        'cond' => $cond, // optional, and "condition" option in the old driver
        'finalize' => $finalize, // optional
    ]
] );

$manager->executeCommand( $ns, $cmd );
```

The `$manager` can be used with the new *extension*, but the new library does not have access to it yet (that's tracked in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-186)